# How to process results of MySQL Select using the IN Operator

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to figure out an efficient way to select a small list of random ids from a table.

Using the IN operator seems like the right choice, but I don't understand how use the results the way I want. After the query is made how do I use the results to assign to specific variables? or is there a way to assign the values as part of the query?

```
$red_car1=1001;
$blue_car2=200;
$green_car3=56;


$query_cars= sprintf("SELECT * FROM cars WHERE id IN (%s, %s, %s)", $red_car1, $blue_car4, $green_car3);
$Cars1 = mysql_query($query_cars, $db) or die(mysql_error());

$red_car1_vin = $row_Cars1['vin'];
$blue_car1_vin = $row_Cars1['vin'];
$green_car1_vin = $row_Cars1['vin'];
```

Comment: What server side languare are you using?

Comment: i'm using php language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get yourself familiar with prepared statements. Prepare your statement once and execute it n times with n variables. It's quite efficient.
Or itterate over your results:

```
$tmp = array();
while($row_Cars1 = mysql_fetch_array($Cars1))
{
    $tmp[$row_Cars1['id']] = $row_Cars1;    
}
```

Now you have an associative array with your results and you can use it like:

```
$red_car1_vin = $tmp[$red_car1];
```

Answer (score 0):

If your server side language is PHP, then your code should be like -

```
     $con=mysqli_connect("your host","user","password","your db");

     $red_car1=1001;
        $blue_car2=200;
        $green_car3=56;


        $query_cars= "SELECT * FROM cars WHERE id 
        IN (".$red_car1.",".$blue_car2.",".$green_car3.")";
        $Cars1 = mysqli_query($con,$query_cars) or die(mysql_error());

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($Cars1))
      {
      echo $row['<<Your Desired field name1>>'] . " " . $row['<<Your Desired field name2>>'];// and so on
      echo "<br />";
      }

mysqli_close($con);
```

Also you can have more helpful information here -http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp

Thanks